# fast convert string_view to floating point

Tags: c++, converting

The code makes following assumptions:

- `std::string_view` is not null-terminated
- there are no exponents, all floating point inputs are in the way 123.123
- limiting digits before and after decimal point
- `<ctype.h>` free. No locale. Uses own `isspace()` and `isdigits()`

---

```
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <string_view>
  #include <limits>
  
  // based on http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/strtod.c.html
  
  namespace to_fp_impl_{
    namespace{
        constexpr char decimal_point = '.';
  
        auto isspace(char c){
            return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
        };
  
        auto isdigit(char c){
            return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
        }
  
        template<typename FP>
        void add_char(FP &number, char c){
            number = number * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
    }
  
    template<typename FP>
    struct ResultFP{
        FP  num;
        bool    ok  = true;
  
        static auto err(){
            return ResultFP{ 0, false };
        }
    };
  } // namespace to_fp_impl_
  
  
  template<
    typename FP,
    uint8_t digits      = std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10,
    uint8_t decimals    = digits
  >
  auto to_fp(std::string_view const str){
    static_assert(
        std::is_floating_point_v<FP>            &&
        digits   <= std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10   &&
        decimals <= std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10
    );
  
    // -----
  
    using namespace to_fp_impl_;
  
    using Result = ResultFP<FP>;
  
    auto it  = std::begin(str);
    auto end = std::end(str);
  
    // -----
  
    // Skip leading whitespace
    while (it != end && isspace(*it))
        ++it;
  
    // -----
  
    // Handle optional sign
    int8_t sign = +1;
  
    if (it != end){
        if (*it == '-'){
            sign = -1;
  
            ++it;
        }else if (*it == '+'){
        //  sign = +1;
  
            ++it;
        }
    }
  
    // -----
  
    FP number = 0.0;
  
    uint8_t total_digits = 0;
  
    // Process digits
    {
        uint8_t num_digits = 0;
        while (it != end && isdigit(*it)){
            if (++num_digits > digits)
                return Result::err();
  
            add_char(number, *it);
            ++it;
        }
  
        total_digits += num_digits;
    }
  
    // -----
  
    // Process decimal part
    if (it != end && *it == decimal_point){
        ++it;
  
        FP exp = 1;
  
        uint8_t num_digits = 0;
        while (it != end && isdigit(*it)){
            if (++num_digits > decimals)
                return Result::err();
  
            add_char(number, *it);
            ++it;
            exp *= 0.1;
        }
  
        total_digits += num_digits;
  
        number *= exp;
    }
  
    // -----
  
    return Result{ number * sign, total_digits != 0 };
  }
  
  template<
    typename FP,
    uint8_t digits      = std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10,
    uint8_t decimals    = digits
  >
  auto to_fp_def(std::string_view const str, FP def = 0){
    auto[num, ok] = to_fp<FP, digits, decimals>(str);
  
    return ok ? num : def;
  }
  
  template<
    uint8_t digits      = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10,
    uint8_t decimals    = digits
  >
  auto to_double_def(std::string_view const str, double def = 0){
    return to_fp_def<double, digits, decimals>(str, def);
  }
  
  template<
    uint8_t digits      = std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10,
    uint8_t decimals    = digits
  >
  auto to_float_def(std::string_view const str, float def = 0){
    return to_fp_def<float, digits, decimals>(str, def);
  }
  
  #include <cstdio>
  
  int main(){
    auto _ = [](const char *s){
        const char *mask = ">%32.15f<\n";
        constexpr double def = -0.111111111111111;
        printf(mask, to_double_def(s, def));
    };
  
    _("    ."               ); //error
    _("   -."               ); //error
    _("   +."               ); //error
  
    _("    .0"              );
    _("   -.0"              );
    _("   +.0"              );
  
    _("   0."               );
    _("  -0."               );
    _("  +0."               );
  
    _("   0"                );
    _("  -0"                );
    _("  +0"                );
  
    _(" 100.1"              );
    _("-100.1"              );
    _("+100.1"              );
  
    _("  123456789012345"           );
    _("  123456789012345."          );
    _("                 .123456789012345"   );
    _("  123456789012345.123456789012345"   ); // OK, but truncated
  
    _("  -123456789012345"          );
    _("  -123456789012345."         );
    _("                 -.123456789012345"  );
    _("  -123456789012345.123456789012345"  ); // OK, but truncated
  
    _(" 1234567890123456."          ); //error, too long
    _("                 .1234567890123456"  ); //error, too long
    _(" 1234567890123456.1234567890123456"  ); //error, too long
  }
```

---

## Result:

```
>              -0.111111111111111<
>              -0.111111111111111<
>              -0.111111111111111<
>               0.000000000000000<
>              -0.000000000000000<
>               0.000000000000000<
>               0.000000000000000<
>              -0.000000000000000<
>               0.000000000000000<
>               0.000000000000000<
>              -0.000000000000000<
>               0.000000000000000<
>             100.100000000000009<
>            -100.100000000000009<
>             100.100000000000009<
> 123456789012345.000000000000000<
> 123456789012345.000000000000000<
>               0.123456789012345<
> 123456789012345.250000000000000<
>-123456789012345.000000000000000<
>-123456789012345.000000000000000<
>              -0.123456789012345<
>-123456789012345.250000000000000<
>              -0.111111111111111<
>              -0.111111111111111<
>              -0.111111111111111<
```

---

## Benchmark:

the code is 4.6 x faster than `std::strtod()`, but slower than `std::from_chars()`
https://quick-bench.com/q/cHVL5PW9m4WSp6OvPnrF-ApCrG4

Comment: You claim it is fast. Have you benchmarked it? How much faster is it than `std::strtod()` and `std::from_chars()`?

Comment: I do not claim is fast :) it suppose to be fast. Not handling exponent suppose to make it fast. Strtod may crash on non null terminated string. And from-chars is not always available.

Comment: OK, fair point. is 4.6 x fast than `std::strtod()`, but slower than `std::from_chars()`  
 https://quick-bench.com/q/cHVL5PW9m4WSp6OvPnrF-ApCrG4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## hoist out of loop

Consider comparing `num_digits` to `decimals`
at the very end,
so you bench quicker.

## FP accumulated error

This expression concerns me:

```
            exp *= 0.1;
```

We're supposed to be able to roundtrip *any*
expression between FP and string, losslessly.
Yet this is an inexact representation of 1/10th.

Consider incrementing an integer and then
computing the `exp` multiplier afresh each time
from that integer.

EDIT

Actually, it turns out that this is pretty terrible:

```
        number *= exp;
```

Why?
Because `exp` is inexact.
It is 10 ** -N, e.g. 10 ** -6.
A *much* better approach would be
to assign it 10 ** N, e.g. a million, and compute

```
        number /= exp;
```

In this case we're dividing an exact quantity,
an integer (many integers fit fine within a double),
by another exact quantity: `number / exp`.
Only then do we round-off to 53 bits.

In contrast, the OP code suffers from a *pair* of
rounding operations:

1. infinite repeating binary fraction for 10 ** -N
2. division

Truncating twice, to 53 bits, leads to worse errors.
Try it and see.
Good examples are `0.3` and `0.7`.
We don't want to obtain a result
like 0.30000000000000004
or 0.7000000000000001 -- we'd much
rather be able to roundtrip back and forth
without such noise creeping in.

---

There is a subtler difficulty with this computation.
The [spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest)
requires rounding toward an even number in some cases.

Let's back up a moment.
A 64-bit `double` doesn't quite represent **a** number.
Rather, it represents an interval on the real number line,
bounded by adjacent bit patterns.
Here, "adjacent" pretty much corresponds to
C cast punning where you treat the significand
bits as an int and use the `++` increment operator.
While the real number line is infinitely divisible,
FP space consists of a finite number of adjacent intervals
(plus NaNs, infinities, and that whole `-0.0` thing).

So the double `1.0` covers 1 through 1+ϵ,
and `2.0` covers 2 through 2 plus a slightly bigger epsilon.
If our division result falls within that ϵ interval,
then we can roundtrip back and forth all day long
without noise, going from string to double to string to double.
Many numbers are amenable to this, such as `0.2` and even `0.3`.
They are infinite repeating binary fractions
which we truncate to 53 bits and obtain a perfectly nice result.
The fraction goes on infinitely but it lands squarely
within an interval.
The truncation can be viewed as appending an
infinite number of zeros on the end.

For a number that appears to land right on an
interval boundary, when rounding to 53 bits we're
required to round to even.
Kind of a tricky requirement.
Again, this is like having infinite zeros to the right.

Here is an example ASCII string which illustrates this:
`"0.8750000000582075"`.
The correct `to_fp()` result would be
0.8750000000582076 rather than
0.8750000000582075.
Once we see that ...76 ending in the double,
we can roundtrip to string to double to string
all day long and it remains ...76.

The underlying representation for ...75, and for ...76, is
`0x1.c00000007ffffp-1`, while for ...77 it is
`0x1.c000000080000p-1`.

Comment: FP accumulated error - I did changed this to a lookup array with values 1, 0.1, 0.01 and so on. If I benchmark it. Is not faster, but probably error is smaller. However I dont get what do you mean with comparison - what / how do you mean to do it?

Comment: I understand what you mean. That's very clever :) however, if I do it, nobody will understand the code. Also there may be a case like 5.1 where both are equal to 1. So may be better way will be to use bool, but still the code will became hard to understand.

Comment: A "slightly bigger" epsilon is actually twice the size, because that's where we move up to the next exponent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any benefit to `ResultFP` over simply using a `std::optional` type, which is already familiar to users rather than something new to learn.

The helper functions could (and probably should) be declared `constexpr`.

`std::uint8_t` is written throughout as `uint8_t` as if we'd included `<stdint.h>` rather than `<cstdint>`.  Also, in the test program, `std::printf` is similarly misspelt.

Is `std::uint8_t` really the appropriate type for counting?  `std::uint_fast8_t` seems a better choice, since it's guaranteed to exist.  Or perhaps just use `int` for consistency with `std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10`.

I'm not sure why we limit the integral and fractional components to `digits10`.  That restricts us to quite a small portion of the floating-point range; consider `max_exponent10` and `digits10-min_exponent10` respectively for full coverage.

I'd prefer separate `static_assert()`s for the three tests - that gives more informative feedback to client code which violates them.  We should also test that `digits` and `decimals` aren't both zero.

We're missing an include of `<iterator>` for the declarations of `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.  However, it's simpler just to use `std::string_view`'s member `begin()` and `end()` here.

As [J_H's answer](/a/286062/75307) points out, we should avoid inexact numbers such as `0.1` or `1 / 10.`  The easy way to do this is to maintain `FP divisor{1}` and multiply that by `10.0` each time we read a digit from the fractional part.  And at the end, return `number / divisor`.

The test program is better than nothing, but we have a ready-made source of truth we can compare against in the standard library, so we could make sure that we get the same results as `std::strtod()` and similar, and make the tests *self-checking*.  We don't test any template arguments other than the defaults, so it's quite a weak test.  Also, we don't test enough invalid inputs (the empty string would generally be my first test, when I'm deciding on the interface, for example).

I'm not a big fan of the name `_` for the test function.

My suggested replacement:

```
#include <limits>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

template<
    typename FP = double,
    int digits = std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10,
    int decimals = digits
    >
std::optional<FP> to_fp(std::string_view const str) {
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<FP>);
    static_assert(0 <= digits);
    static_assert(0 <= decimals);
    static_assert(digits + decimals);
    static_assert(digits   <= std::numeric_limits<FP>::max_exponent10);
    static_assert(decimals <= std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10-std::numeric_limits<FP>::min_exponent10);

    static auto const isspace = [](char c){
        return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
    };

    static auto const isdigit = [](char c){
            return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
    };

    static auto const add_char = [](FP &number, char c){
        number = number * 10 + (c - '0');
    };

    // -----

    auto it = str.begin();
    auto const end = str.end();

    // Skip leading whitespace
    while (it != end && isspace(*it)) {
        ++it;
    }
    if (it == end) { return {}; }

    // Handle optional sign
    FP sign = +1;
    if (*it == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        ++it;
    } else if (*it == '+') {
        ++it;
    }

    FP number = 0.0;
    bool digits_seen = false;
    // Process integer part
    for (int num_digits = 0;  it != end && isdigit(*it);  ++it) {
        if (++num_digits > digits) { return {}; }
        add_char(number, *it);
        digits_seen = true;
    }

    // Process decimal part
    if (it == end || *it != '.') { return sign * number; }
    ++it;

    FP divisor = 1;
    for (int num_digits = 0;  it != end && isdigit(*it);  ++it) {
        if (++num_digits > decimals) { return {}; }
        add_char(number, *it);
        digits_seen = true;
        divisor *= 10;
    }

    if (!digits_seen) { return {}; }

    return sign * number / divisor;
}

template<
    typename FP,
    int digits      = std::numeric_limits<FP>::digits10,
    int decimals    = digits
    >
auto to_fp_def(std::string_view const str, FP def = 0){
    return to_fp<FP, digits, decimals>(str).value_or(def);
}
```

There's still a tiny optimisation that can be made by tweaking the sign bit instead of multiplying by `sign`.

And it still fails to round correctly in the least-significant digit.